# How to send multiple attachments via email and user must attach file for button to work

Tags: java, android, email-attachments

I have an activity where I would like the user to attach 2 files before he/she sends the email. If they don't attach I would like the app to alert user that the first attachment is not uploaded and the same for the 2nd attachment.

My Java code is as follows:

```
etEmail = findViewById(R.id.etTo);
    etSubject = findViewById(R.id.etSubject);
    attachment = findViewById(R.id.btAttachment);
    Attachment = findViewById(R.id.tvAttachment);
    IDAttachment = findViewById(R.id.idAttachment);
    idattachment = findViewById(R.id.id2Attachment);
    Name = findViewById(R.id.yourName);
    Number = findViewById(R.id.cellNumber);
    Send = findViewById(R.id.btSend);

    Send.setOnClickListener(this);
 attachment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openFolder();
        }
    });
    idattachment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openFolder2();
        }
    });


}

 private void openFolder2() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btSend:
            userLogin();
            break;
    }
}

private void userLogin() {
    String yourName = Name.getText().toString().trim();
    String cellNumber = Number.getText().toString().trim();
    String tvAttachment = Attachment.getText().toString().trim();
    String idattachment1 = IDAttachment.getText().toString().trim();

    if (yourName.isEmpty()) {
        Name.setError("Full name is required!");
        Name.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if (cellNumber.isEmpty()) {
        Number.setError("Cell number is required!");
        Number.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if (cellNumber.length() < 10) {
        Number.setError("Cell number is too short");
        Number.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (idattachment1.isEmpty()) {
        IDAttachment.setError("ID copy not uploaded");
        IDAttachment.requestFocus();
        return;

    }
    if (tvAttachment.isEmpty()) {
        Attachment.setError("Payslip not uploaded!");
        Attachment.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    else  Send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendEmail();
        }
    });
}

private void closeFab() {
    fab.startAnimation(rotateBackwards);
    imageMenu.startAnimation(fabClose);
    imageMenu.setClickable(false);
    gridView.startAnimation(fabClose);
    gridView.setClickable(false);
    ShadowView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    isOpen = false;
}

private void openFolder() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        URI = data.getData();
        Attachment.setText(URI.getLastPathSegment());
        IDAttachment.setText(URI.getLastPathSegment());
        Attachment.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        IDAttachment.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}

private void sendEmail() {
    try {
        email = "kondja99@gmail.com";
        subject = etSubject.getText().toString();
        message = "Full Name: " + Name.getText().toString() + "\n" + "Cellphone No: " + Number.getText().toString();
        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "kondja99@gmail.com");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        if (URI != null) {
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, URI);
        }
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
        this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Sending email..."));
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Request failed, retry! " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

My XML code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradient_drawable"
tools:context=".Activity7">


<!-- Application Page -->


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView15"
                android:layout_width="72dp"
                android:layout_height="103dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/key_icon" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/etSubject"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Application"
                android:textSize="1dp"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@color/blue"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/etTo"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background_transparent"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="1dp"
                android:text="kondja99@gmail.com"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@color/blue"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etSubject"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout2">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/yourName"
                android:layout_width="235dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background_transparent"
                android:ems="10"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/orange"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView17"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView17" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView17"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/full_name_button" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout5">

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout3">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/cellNumber"
                android:layout_width="235dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background_transparent"
                android:ems="10"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:text=""
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/orange"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView18"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView18" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView18"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/cell_number_button" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout13"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout7">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/idAttachment"
            android:layout_width="215dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout14"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout12">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/id2Attachment"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/idatachment_selector"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout12"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout7">


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/tvAttachment"
                android:layout_width="215dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="210dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout12">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btAttachment"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/upload_selector"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btSend"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/submit_selector"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btAttachment"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.200" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

What I want is when I press submit the app should set an error stating that I have not attached the required documents, I've done this for the text views for "Name: and Cell No.". I've put a text view underneath each attachment button to enable the "Set Alert" if user has not attached any file.

Comment: The user does not attach anything. But you can let the user select two files before you would send an email with those two files attached. What exactly is the problem? There is no onActivityResult code so we have no idea what you do with the two obtained file uries.

Comment: I will update my post then you should see onActivityResult

Comment: `Attachment.setText(URI.getLastPathSegment());` That makes no sense as you should save/remember the whole choosen urie and only saving that part of it brings you nowhere. Better: `Attachment.setText(URI.toString());`

Comment: But you did not further tell your problem(although i asked for it) and you are already checking with  if (tvAttachment.isEmpty()) if the user has choosen a file. So now again: what exactly is your problem?

Comment: You will have two triggers of onActivityResult but i dont see you hanle two different occasions/files.

Comment: `PICK_FROM_GALLERY` If the user has to pick two files and if you wanna thread those files differently then you need two request codes like `PICK_FILE1_FROM_GALLERY` and `PICK_FILE2_FROM_GALLERY`.

Comment: `private void openFolder()` ??? You mean: `private void pickFile()` ? Please make your code readable.

Comment: Thanks , I will quickly try this method of yours!

Comment: I am still a bit new to coding in java, I learned through a couple of courses. My apology.

Comment: My problem is , I want to attach 1 file for each button, the buttons are 2 then only I can send the email. If I don't complete these requests, the app alerts me that I have not attached the files for each button.

Comment: Yes we know. I gave you hints. I dont understand what you miss

Comment: I think the problem I created was add a text view under each button to alert user, how does one alert user with button. Can I only give a toast that user did not attach file?

Comment: Yes. And you disable the button to send a mail until all is filled in as it should.